# Android Firebase regarding the unique id

Tags: android

Currently i working on Firebase database. I want to retrieve the blue circle unique id but it always retrieve the red circle unique id. Does anyone know how to do this? [This is the image when i click one of the item in list view, it will match whether it match or not. If match then go to next activity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZyhR.png) I'm want to retrieve the blue circle unique id so that i pass it to next activity and use that blue circle unique id to retrieve the data that store in Firebase database.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
ref.child("Confirmed Booking").child(nUniqueId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }
```

Comment: Do you have saw my image?

Comment: yes, use dataSnapshot.getKey() to get the blue circle unique id. if it doesn't work, check your security rules or maybe you should use String.valueOf(nUniqueId) instead of nUniqueId when you set the database reference.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change this:

```
String key = dataSnapshot.child("Confirmed Booking").child(nUniqueId).getKey();
```

to:

```
for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
{
String key = snapshot.getKey();
}
```

Comment: @M.Wagas.Pervez